# Display Document count from Firebase in a Text Widget in Flutter Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, count, document

I am working on an admin web which i wanna to display some data like total users or total sales at the dashboard. But after much findings, I am not able to display the data in a Text Widget.

This is the home.dart

```
int placeCount = 0;
  countDocuments() async {
    
    QuerySnapshot myDoc2 =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Places').get();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> myDocCount2 = myDoc2.docs;
    this.placeCount = myDocCount2.length;
    print(this.placeCount);
 
    // Count of Documents in Collection
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    countDocuments();
    super.initState();
  }

//The way  of displaying the data in Text Widget
Text(this.placeCount),
```

The result is the count print at the console is correct, but the count data display at the text widget will be initialization number i did which was 0. Is it something wrong i did that the placeCount cannot grab the correct data count from the countDocuments() method? Someone please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the satet of your variable, call

```
setState(() {
  this.placeCount = myDocCount2.length;
});
```

this should update the value

Comment: Great! :) consider marking the answer as correct if it solved your problem the way you expected it to.